# Skype versions higher then 5.x blocking TextMate Scroll - Line up binding

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, skype, textmate

I've a very unpleasant issue. Skype is actually blocking a key binding to be triggered from within TextMate. Let me explain this a bit further.

I noticed that CTRL+ALT+CMD UP didn't trigger Scroll - Line up in TextMate, version 2.0 (9090). I read http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/KeyBindings and I quote:

> TextMate is simply not seeing the key stroke. This might be because you have another program which eats the key.

So I started to browse through all my open application in order to find any application having the same key binding. Finally, I found out that Skype is causing this behavior because of it's hidden key binding **Push To Talk**.

> This morning I received a nice note from Skype's product manager for the Skype for Mac product letting me know that this "Push To Talk" feature actually is included in the Skype for Mac 5.x Beta releases, albeit as a hidden feature.  To use "Push To Talk" during a Skype call, you need to press (ready for this?):
>
> > Control + Option + Command + Up Arrow

I've tried to find any way possible to inactivate, rebind, unbind or similar in Skype to fix this issue but I'm still without luck. Do anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**A.** 
it seems to be configurable in version 5.9. 
go to  --> tools --> options --> advanced --> Hotkeys...

**B.** why not trying an alternative Skype client, for example [Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/)

I haven't used it myself for years now, but it seems to support just about anything including Skype according to the [adding accounts](http://help.trillian.im/kb/windows/adding-accounts) section of the help

**C.** another idea might be running Skype inside a virtual machine, but this sound too much like an overkill